# Twitter Bootstrap: Unable to make website responsive for smaller device

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am developing a project for school and I am pretty new to Bootstrap and I keep having some problems with scaling the website for different resolutions. When I change it to mobile the images go on top of the text. If anybody could help me I would appreciate it.
I have tried everything and still cant find a solution.

```
<body>
  
<div class="container">
    
<nav class="navbar-fixed-top sticky-top navbar" style="width: 100%; background-color: white; box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.19), 0 6px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.23);"> 
    
    <div class="navbar-header">
    
        <a class="navbar-brand"><img src="transferir.png" alt="" style="height: 65; width: 60px"></a>
        
    </div> 
    
    <div>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#sobre">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#features">Features</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contacta-nos</a></li>
        </ul>    
    </div>
        
</nav>


    
<div class="site-index">
    
    <div id="home" class="block home-block">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-sm-6  left-block">
                <div class="text-centered">
                    <h1>Texter</h1>
                    <p class="info-text">Send text messages, voice messages, video messages or video call with all your friends and family easily, quickly and securely.</p>
                    
                    <p class="Medium-text">Download Em Breve</p>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/?hl=pt-PT" target="_blank"><img src="playstore.png" alt="Playstore" class="d-img"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.apple.com/pt/ios/app-store/" target="_blank"><img src="appstore.png" alt="Apple App Store" class="d-img"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5  right-block">
                <img src="phones.png" style="height: 350px; float: right; vertical-align: middle; width: auto !important; position: relative">            
            </div>   
        </div>
        <hr class="sombra">
    </div>
</div>
```

Css

```
html{
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body{
    padding-top: 1%;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.block{
    padding: 35px;
}

.home-block{
    min-height: calc(100vh - 90px);
}

#home .container{
    height: 500px;  
}

.left-block{
    text-align: center;
    top: 30%;     
}

.right-block{
    bottom: 35%;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.container{
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

[Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Rhqm.png)

[When i squish the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imld2.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, use the `code snippet` button to display your code (or press Ctrl+M in your post editor). Your images are displayed incorrectly, you could try providing a full link with your domain name (if you have your website hosted somewhere) or using special tools like https://picsum.photos/ to display another image with the same size. Also, please provide a link to your bootstrap version. P. S. my personal recommendation - do not use bootstrap, nowadays every markup can be done without using CSS frameworks

Comment: Is it a requirement to use Bootstrap?

Comment: No, its a free project

Comment: I am not getting something, i upload my file to the vps, and on my normal chrome the website is all deformated, and on my brackets chrome previewer is like it should be, what do you think the problem is?

Comment: Vps : [link](http://51.140.77.230/) Works like it should with brackets previewer but with normal chrome its deformated

Comment: Using chrome : [link](https://i.imgur.com/xz0XDnd.png)

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted - press check mark under the vote buttons. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably forgot to include `<div class="row"></div>` wrapper inside your `<div class="container">...</div>` element, just as it says [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#how-it-works).

Secondly, I strongly recommend you to not play too much with CSS properties such as `position: relative`/`absolute`, `top: ...; left: ...; right: ...; bottom: ...`, because most of them break the CSS native document flow and they should be used only when other tools do not help much.

I suggest you reading this series of articles if you have enough time: [CSS layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout)

I turned off most of the properties of that kind and it already looks much nicer:

[image: HTML layout corrected by disabling some CSS properties]

This answer would be just be a massive advice if I wouldn't provide some code help, so here it is.

Start by disabling these properties in DevTools:

```
.home-block{
    /* min-height: calc(100vh - 90px); */
}

#home .container{
    /* height: 500px; */
}

.left-block{
    /* text-align: center; */
    /* top: 30%; */
}

.right-block{
    /* bottom: 35%; */
    /* margin-left: 25%; */
}
```

Fixing Bootstrap markup:

```
<div id="home" class="block home-block">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Added this wrapper, changed .col-* classes to responsive -->
        <div class="row">
            <!-- Removed .left-block class -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6  left-block">
                <div class="text-centered">
                    <h1>Texter</h1>
                    <p class="info-text">Send text messages, voice messages, video messages or video call with all your friends and family easily, quickly and securely.</p>
                    <p class="Medium-text">Download Em Breve</p>
                    <a href="https://play.google.com/?hl=pt-PT" target="_blank"><img src="playstore.png" alt="Playstore" style="height: 40px;"></a>
                    <a href="https://www.apple.com/pt/ios/app-store/" target="_blank"><img src="appstore.png" alt="Apple App Store" style="height: 40px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Removed .right-block class, added .text-centered class -->
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 text-centered">
                <!-- Removed inline styles (bad practice), changed "height" to be an attribute -->
                <img src="phones.png" height="350">            
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you would get this picture (no interval between image and the button on the top):

[image: No interval between image and the button on the top]

This one is solved by applying `margin-top: ...px;` to the image block, wrapped in `@media` query at `.col-md-*` resolutions and lower. For the exact values see [Bootstrap grid options](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#grid-options). For more info on applying `@media` queries see [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media)

As for navigation bar, I first suggest you disabling `padding-left` on `ul#menu` element:

```
#menu {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

Although it fixes it on `sm` resolutions, the navigation menu still wraps under the logo on resolutions less than about `520px`. I suggest you imagine what to do with this occasion in your mind or in some markup service like https://app.diagrams.net/ and then develop what you decided to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
</head>
```

See [this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) and [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/)